# Dark scene with object contours by light reflections

Tags: studio-lighting, darkness, cars, silhouette

I am interested in the type of photos as the first two in this article:

http://www.transportationdesign.se/blog/2015/09/headlights-defining-a-brand-and-creating-a-character/

(or search google images for "dark car headlight")

It is popular for car revelations or catalog photos. I even cannot remember seeing these photos with something else but cars. You cannot see every detail of the object but just the basic (most important) ones and sharp headlights.

Is there a special name for this kind of photography?

How can I take a photo like this at home with some rather small objects like a car model or a quadcopter?

Comment: I can't justify posting this as an answer, but look into "low-key photography"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photographs like the ones you mentioned are retouched. Please don't expect to take photo like these just with a few strobes and no retouching.

Key elements to take care of

- increase the **brightness** of the **object's lights** (indicator lights, headlights, etc.)
- **reduce** any unwanted **light sources** that reflect off of your object (daylight, windows, light bulbs, street lights, etc.)
- **underexpose** heavily
- ideally choose a dark/**black object** with a **glossy finish**
- use light sources that throw light onto your object from behind without being visible in the viewfinder to accentuate the silhouette (think **hair light**)
- choose an **object with a smooth surface**